# What's the meaning of if [ -z "$SPARK_HOME" ]; then

Tags: bash, shell, conditional-statements

Full script:

```
if [ -z "$SPARK_HOME" ]; then
  echo "SPARK_HOME must be set to the location of a Spark distribution!"
  exit 1
fi
```

My guess is if there is no setting for `"$SPARK_HOME"` then do the following, however I double checked with echo `$SPARK_HOME` and do see value set in it.

```
$echo $SPARK_HOME
/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2
```

Currently a script errors out here saying

> SPARK_HOME must be set to the location of a Spark distribution!

How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: alright, thank you.

Comment: Make sure the variable is exported and that you're running the script from the same shell, otherwise it may not be set in the script